# GetMenuItemInfo, but i´m getting a 1456 - "Menu item not found"

Tags: c#, winapi, menuitem

im trying to know if a menuItem is disabled or enabled, but i´m getting a 1456 - "Menu item not found"
what am I doing wrong

in the first part is the declaration of the win32 libraries.

menuIndex is a parameter int
submenuIndex is another parameter int

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct MENUITEMINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint fMask;
        public uint fType;
        public uint fState;
        public uint wID;
        public IntPtr hSubMenu;
        public IntPtr hbmpChecked;
        public IntPtr hbmpUnchecked;
        public IntPtr dwItemData;
        public string dwTypeData;
        public uint cch;
        public IntPtr hbmpItem;

        // return the size of the structure
        public static uint sizeOf
        {
            get { return (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUITEMINFO)); }
        }
    }

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetMenu(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetSubMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPos);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetMenuItemID(IntPtr hMenu, int nPos);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool GetMenuItemInfo(IntPtr hMenu, int uItem, bool fByPosition, ref MENUITEMINFO lpmii);

....

IntPtr menu = GetMenu(handle);

IntPtr subMenu = GetSubMenu(menu, menuIndex);

uint menuItemID = GetMenuItemID(subMenu, submenuIndex);

MENUITEMINFO itemInfo = new MENUITEMINFO();
uint MIIM_STATE = 0x00000001;
itemInfo.cbSize = MENUITEMINFO.sizeOf;
itemInfo.fMask = MIIM_STATE;

if (!GetMenuItemInfo(menu, (int)submenuIndex, false, ref itemInfo))
{
    uint erro = GetLastError();
    //erro = 1456
    throw new Exception("Ocorreu um erro ao obter informações do Menu Centura - Cod: "+Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString() +"\n http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx");
}                    

if (itemInfo.fState == MFS_DISABLED)
    throw new Exception("Disabled");

PostMessage(handle, 0x0111, (IntPtr)menuItemID, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: can you please format the code as well as show what method and or event handler you are executing the code from .. also have you even stepped thru the code..? what does the GetMenuItemId() method look like.. please show all relevant code that pertains to the issue and or error(s) that you are experiencing

Comment: ...especially where submenuIndex comes from...

Comment: also `itemInfo.cbSize = MENUITEMINFO.sizeOf;` should that be 
`itemInfo.sizeOF` or something like that instead.. you create an Instance of MENUITEMINFO but you should be using the variable to access it's properties not the Base itself.. what does `MENUITEMINFO` look like.. I would also read up on `Naming Conventions for C# .Net` would really help you..

Comment: submenuIndex is a parameter int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `false` for the `fByPosition` argument, so you need to pass a menu ID (`menuItemID`), not an index (`submenuIndex`).  You also need to pass a handle to the menu that contains the item (`subMenu`, not `menu`).

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says

> *`fByPosition`* `[in]`
>
> Type: `BOOL`
>
> The meaning of `uItem`. If this parameter is `FALSE`, `uItem` is a menu item identifier. Otherwise, it is a menu item position. See [Accessing Menu Items Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553(v=vs.85).aspx#accessing_menu_items_programmatically) for more information.

Either of these might work:

```
GetMenuItemInfo(subMenu, (int)submenuIndex, true, ref itemInfo)

GetMenuItemInfo(subMenu, (int)menuItemID, false, ref itemInfo)
```